# Debugging in OpenERP 7.0

Tags: odoo

How to do debug in OpenERP v7?

In previous versions of OpenERP, it was easy to debug. But in the latest version it's tough to debug.

Comment: How do you debug in the previous version?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To debug your OpenERP+python code in eclipse, start eclipse (helios/indigo only) in debug perspective and follow the given steps:

1: Stop your openERP running server by pressing "ctr+c".

2: In eclipse go to Menu "Run/Debug Configurations". In configuration window under "Python Run", create new debug configuration(Double click on 'Python Run').

3: After creating new debug configuration follow the given steps:

3.1: In "Main" tab under "Project", select the "server" project or folder (in which Openerp Server resides) from your workspace.

3.2: Write location of 'openerp-server' under "Main Module".

```
Ex: ${workspace_loc:server/openerp-server}.
```

3.3: In "Arguments" tab under "Program Arguments", click on button "Variables" and new window will appear.

3.4: Then create new "Variable" by clicking on "Edit Variables" button and new window will appear.

3.5: Press on "New" button and give your addons path as value.

```
Ex: --addons ../addons,../your_module_path
```

3.6: Press Ok in all the opened windows and then "Apply".

4: Now into "PyDev Package Explorer" view go to 6.1/server and right click on "openerp-server" file, Select 'Debug As --> Python Run'.

5: Now in "Console" you can see your server has been started.

6: Now open your .py file which you want to debug and set a break-point.

7: Now start your module's form from 'gtk' or 'web-client' and execution will stop when execution will reach to break-point.

8: Now enjoy by debugging your code by pressing "F5, F6, F7" and you can see value of your variables.

You can refer following link: [Debug OpenERP Code from Eclipse](http://debug-openerp-python-code-in-eclipse.blogspot.in/)

Comment: You can directly run `openerp-server.py` (v6.0), `openerp-server` (v6.1, v7) 'Debug As --> Python Run'. from eclipse. After that server configuration will be done automatically and you just have to give addons path as given in step: 3.5

Answer (score 5):

Go to Administrator(in right top corner) in that click on `About OpenERP` in that you will find a link `Activate the Developer Mode`.
or 
you can add a parameter`debug` in of URL like

```
 http://localhost:8069/?debug
```

both the way will let you open the developer mode.

You can also use the [Odoo Debug pro chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/odoo-debug-pro/nfnladagngmiggfaojdbpjdpehdfgiac) to toggle the developer mode using the keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

To debug openERP 7 from eclipse just Stop openERP server and rename the main file named openerp-server.py.From "Run/Debug Configurations" make a new configuration selecting Project and main module such as ${workspace_loc:openerp7/src/openerp-server.py} then press Apply.After that /openerp7/src/openerp-server.py 'Debug As --> Python Run' using new configuration.Server is running where pydev debugger is also started.Now run 'gtk' or 'web-client'.Then select the python file of that module where want to debug and give breakpoints.That's all.

Answer (score 1):

Debugging is quite simple in interface.

**For Programmers**

By Default when you login to openerp, your url will look something like this

```
http://localhost:7373/?db=Test_July_25#menu_id=107&action=97
```

Edit the url and add **debug=&**

localhost:7373/?debug=&db=Test_July_25#menu_id=107&action=97

**For Functional Users**

- Navigate mouse to top right corner and select About OpenERP

[image]

- Now Activate Debug Mode

[image]

You Should be done now with interface debugging.

**For Code Debugging** (along with arya's method these images may help you)

- You can use browse button to select the project and the openerp server file

[image]

[image]

Finally place breakpoints in your code where ever necessary

Answer (score 0):

Navigate through
   administrator(top Right)>>about OpenERP
  Dialog Open  Click on Activate Developer mode

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @ebramtharwat it's not clear from the question if this is what the user meant or not. The developer mode is indeed pretty useful to debug issues as it gives a lot of good hints. It can print workflows as an example.

Answer (score 0):

Their is more complexity and less control by adding more fancy tools try and go low level and use python pdb and if you are debug geek then use winpdb with pdb which gives extreme contorl over your code navigation.

And for simple value abd flow use print or pprint module from python.

Bests.

Answer (score 0):

Start debug mode on browser ??
 In URL you can type **?debug** after web
[image]

**OR**

go to **About OpenERP** select **Activate Developer Mode**

If You want to debug from **eclipse** then

go to PyDev Package Explorer --> openerp(odoo) --> Right click on openerp-server file [image]
Select Debug as --> Python Run

It will ask for change current perspective from PyDev to Debug click "Yes" and its Done

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Activate the Debug mode and use some print statements to debug the variable values