# break points not working in eclipse Juno with openerp 7.0

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, odoo

I followed the answer from [Debugging in OpenERP 7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703644/debugging-in-openerp-7-0)
And everything is working right, except for the break points, eclipse never stops at them.
I even added a print line and made a break point on it (right click "add break point"), and it is shown in the console but the break point just did not work.

What am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you start openerp-server with "Debug As->Python Run" option?

Might be you are runing openerp-server with "Run As->Python Run" that is why execution does not stop at given break point.

Comment: Now It's working.
I'm kind off clueless, I was pretty sure I clicked on debug as...
Thank you very much hehe

Answer (score 1):

rename your openerp-server file to openerp-server.py
then follow the Arya's steps  :-)

in my PC its work perfectly with that configuration.